# Typeerror in PuLp (Linear Programming Solver) : 'float' object is not iterable

Tags: reinforcement-learning, linear-programming, pulp

```
Lp_prob = pulp.LpProblem('Problem', pulp.LpMinimize)
V = []
for i in range(numStates[0]):
    var = pulp.LpVariable( "V"+str(i) )
    V.append(var)


total_cost = 0
for i in range(numStates[0]):
    total_cost += V[i]
Lp_prob += total_cost

for i in range(numStates[0]):
    for j in range(numActions[0]):
        matrix_possible = []
        for item in T:
            if item[0] == i and item[1] == j:
                matrix_possible.append(item)
        for m in range(len(matrix_possible)):
            Lp_prob += (V[i] >= pulp.lpSum(  matrix_possible[m][4]*(  matrix_possible[m][3] + gamma*V[int(matrix_possible[m][2])]  )  ))
status = Lp_prob.solve()
```

List V stores the variables V0...Vn that are to be found by linear programming. The error is in line:

```
Lp_prob += (V[i] >= pulp.lpSum(  matrix_possible[m][4]*(  matrix_possible[m][3] + gamma*V[int(matrix_possible[m][2])]  )  ))
```

Matrix possible is a list of lists with m denoting the the list inside it and the second number denoting the index in that list. I don't know why optimiser is giving error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/cry.py", line 233, in <module>
print(lp('data/mdp/continuing-mdp-10-5.txt','vi'))
File "/Users/cry.py", line 219, in lp
Lp_prob += (V[i] >= pulp.lpSum(  matrix_possible[m][4]*(  matrix_possible[m][3] + gamma*V[int(matrix_possible[m][2])]  )  ))
File "/Users/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pulp/pulp.py", line 937, in __radd__
return self.copy().addInPlace(other)
File "/Users/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pulp/pulp.py", line 899, in addInPlace
self.constant += other
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

Can someone help with solving this error please?

The top two lines in the image consist of the T and the third line is the matrix_possible for the case i=0 and j=0, the matrix T list is in order : [s0, a, s1, r, T(p)]

[\image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mq9xa.png)

Answer (score 0):

Something is fishy here.  Your construct is a bit odd, but it appears it should work.  I mocked it up (below) and it computes just fine.

If you are still stuck, you might try printing the value of `matrix_possible` before the pulp statement, or using a debugger.

If you are still stuck after that, you should edit your post above and include a small snippet of the collection `T` which can reproduce the error you are having...  chop it down to a fully contained small example--which is best practice anyhow if you have a pesky error.

```
import pulp

prob = pulp.LpProblem('example')
V = []
for i in range(3):
    V.append(pulp.LpVariable("V" + str(i)))

gamma=0.5
matrix_possible = [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -0.9, 0.3],[0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.93, 0.65]]

for m in range(len(matrix_possible)):
    prob += (V >= pulp.lpSum(  
        matrix_possible[m][4]*(  matrix_possible[m][3] + gamma*V[int(matrix_possible[m][2])]  )  ))

print(prob)
```

#### Output:

```
example:
MINIMIZE
None
SUBJECT TO
_C1: - V0 - V1 - V2 <= 0.27

_C2: - V0 - V1 - V2 <= -0.6045

VARIABLES
V0 free Continuous
V1 free Continuous
V2 free Continuous
```

Comment: I have added the snippet of T as well as matrix_possible

Comment: numStates = 2, numActions = 2 in this example

Comment: There's still something amiss here.  I suspect there is something missing with the code you pasted or a format issue.  All that matters in the construction of that constraint is what `matrix_possible` is.  I used values & structure you provided and it works.  Consider printing it right before the constraint and see what you get.  Or edit your post with the exact code and data (your whole model is not needed) such that somebody can cut/paste it and **see the error.**